# Creating google cloud build triggers using gcloud alpha commands

Tags: json, github, google-cloud-platform, triggers, continuous-integration

I am attempting to create a Google Cloud Build trigger for a github repository using `gcloud alpha builds triggers create github`. I have created a BuildTrigger json containing my trigger config. My end goal is to create a trigger for pull requests in github repositories, which is a small change to the json file.

My json file:

`committrigger.json`

```
{
  "description": "Commit to master branch",
  "name": "Master-Commit",
  "tags": ["test-flask-server"],
  "github": {
    "owner": "zamerman",
    "name": "github_zamerman_test-flask-server",
    "push": {
      "branch": "master"
    }
  },
  "disabled": false,
  "filename": "/cloudbuild.yaml"
}
```

My command to create the trigger: `gcloud alpha builds triggers create github --trigger-config committrigger.json`

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not
exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=429437829619
to connect a repository to your project
```

Help or advice of any kind would be welcome. Thank you.

`gcloud alpha builds triggers create github --trigger-config committrigger.json --verbosity=debug`:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.alpha.builds.triggers.create.github] with arguments: [--trigger-config: "committrigger.json", --verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: (gcloud.alpha.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=429437829619 to connect a repository to your project
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 784, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/builds/triggers/create/github.py", line 169, in Run
    buildTrigger=trigger, projectId=project))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/cloudbuild/v1/cloudbuild_v1_client.py", line 353, in Create
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gcplabzamerman/triggers?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '263', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Wed, 25 Sep 2019 22:45:52 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=429437829619 to connect a repository to your project",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
>
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=429437829619 to connect a repository to your project
```

Comment: did you connect your GH repository with GCP through the Cloud Source Repositories? I believe Cloud Build works only with them under the hood, so you first need to mirror that repo. See https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository

Comment: The Github repository is already connected with GCP through the Cloud Source Repositories. But it still doesn't work. It almost seems like the gcloud alpha commands for triggers hasn't been properly implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the terraform configuration 2 weeks ago and it didn't work as well, so this may be for a bug report @zamerman

Comment: Can you let us know the output of 'gcloud alpha builds triggers create github --trigger-config committrigger.json --verbosity=debug'? This is to have a better insight of where the error is ocurring.

Comment: @Oliver Aragon Added the results above

Comment: what happened to this? it is still failing 12/2020

Answer (score 1):

Their github integration is not working at the moment. You can instead use triggerTemplate key to specify the cloud source repository that is connected to your github repo.

Update your configtrigger.json to something along the lines of:

```
{
  "description": "Commit to master branch",
  "name": "Master-Commit",
  "tags": ["test-flask-server"],
  "triggerTemplate": {
    "projectId": "your project id",
    "repoName": "github_zamerman_github_zamerman_test-flask-server",
    "dir": "./",
    "branchName": "master"
  },
  "disabled": false,
  "filename": "/cloudbuild.yaml"
}
```

Comment: Will this pick up on pull requests in the github repo?